# How do I serialize media objects (audio and pictures) for socket transfer?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, windows-phone-7

I want my app to be able to talk to the pc client through sockets.
I already know how to do that for strings.

My question here, I want to be able to send audio files and pictures, how can I convert the iamge/audio file to a string/bit stream and send it?

Here's my class for the socket:

```
public class SocketClient
{
    Socket socket = null;
    static ManualResetEvent clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    const int TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 5000;
    const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    public SocketClient()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    }

    public string Send(string serverName, int portNumber, string data)
    {
        string response = "Timeout";

        if (socket != null)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(serverName, portNumber);

            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                clientDone.Set();
            });

            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);
            clientDone.Reset();
            socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);

            clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "not initialized";
        }
        return response;
    }

    public string Recieve(int portNumber)
    {
        string response = "Timeout";

        if (socket != null)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                    response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                }

                clientDone.Set();
            });

            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);

            clientDone.Reset();
            socket.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);
            clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to modify it to be able to send pictures and audio files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current Send method uses a string property for data. You could rebuild this using a byte array or stream containing the data.

You can use this example to see how to get from an image to stream and back although this doesn't use sockets but the local storage. The principle about how to do it stays the same:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/12/saving-and-loading-captured-image-to-and-from-wp7-isolated-storage.aspx